# How to access key and value from json in golang?

Tags: json, go

I have a struct

```
type Order struct {
    ID string `json:"id"`
    CustomerMobile string `json:"customerMobile"`
    CustomerName string `json:"customerName"`
   }
```

and the json data:

```
[{"Key":"S001", "Record":{"id":"SOO1","customerMobile":"12344566","customerName":"John"}}]
```

How can i access customerMobile key from the above json object?

I have done some research in Google and i found the below solution, but its not working when i apply to my above requirement. Its working with simple json format.

```
jsonByteArray := []byte(jsondata)
 json.Unmarshal(jsonByteArray, &order)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to unmarshal into something that represents the entire JSON object. Your `Order` struct defines part of it, so just define the rest of it, as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Order struct {
    ID             string `json:"id"`
    CustomerMobile string `json:"customerMobile"`
    CustomerName   string `json:"customerName"`
}

type Thing struct {
    Key    string `json:"Key"`
    Record Order  `json:"Record"`
}

func main() {
    jsonByteArray := []byte(`[{"Key":"S001", "Record":{"id":"SOO1","customerMobile":"12344566","customerName":"John"}}]`)
    var things []Thing
    err := json.Unmarshal(jsonByteArray, &things)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", things)
}
```

Comment: how to access the value of customerMobile key

Comment: @helloworld `things[0].Record.CustomerMobile` will give you the Key. Details -   https://play.golang.org/p/kBX6jqdSA-

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to this: https://play.golang.org/p/pruDx70SjW

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

const data = `[{"Key":"S001", "Record":{"id":"SOO1","customerMobile":"12344566","customerName":"John"}}]`

type Orders struct {
    Key    string
    Record Order
}

type Order struct {
    ID             string
    CustomerMobile string
    CustomerName   string
}

func main() {
    var orders []Orders
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &orders); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", orders)
}
```

In this case, I am omitting the [struct tags](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types)